# Change in line slope affecting fill_between

Tags: python, matplotlib, masking

I currently have a curve defined by `(x_orig, y_orig)`, and I want to plot the shaded region between two new curves defined by `(x_orig - c, y_orig)` and `(x_orig + c, y_orig)`. When using matplotlib's fill_betweenx(), it does most of what I want, except when the two curves have opposite signs of their slope, they cross each other and there is nothing filled between them. I actually want the full space between the two filled. Imagine you grab the line `(x_orig - c, y_orig)` and drag it to the right to `(x_orig + c, y_orig)`, I want to shade all of that area. I want to find the points that define the upper and lower shaded region so that I can additionally mask scatter points that happen to be in there.

I originally wrote an overcomplicated function that mostly does what I want, but it doesn't correctly handle the areas where the lines switch slope. Is there a more "pythonic" way of doing something that I want that isn't needlessly complicated?

```
def shaded_region(x_left, x_right, y_left, y_right):
    y_upper = []
    y_lower = []
    y_lower.append(y_left[0])
    y_upper.append(y_left[0])
    #
    s = np.sign((y_left[1] - y_left[0]))
    #
    x_new = []
    x_new.append(x_left[0])
    #
    for i in range(0, len(x_left)-1):
        m = (y_left[i+1] - y_left[i])
        s_new = np.sign(m)
        #
        if s_new == s:
            if m < 0:
                y_upper.append(y_left[i])
                y_lower.append(y_left[i+1])
            if m > 0:
                y_upper.append(y_left[i+1])
                y_lower.append(y_left[i])
            x_new.append((x_left[i+1]+x_right[i])/2)
        else:
            p1 = np.array([x_left[i+1], y_left[i+1]])
            p2 = np.array([x_left[i], y_left[i]])
            p3 = np.array([x_right[i], y_right[i]])
            p4 = np.array([x_right[i-1], y_right[i-1]])
            #
            # print(i)
            # print(p1,p2,p3,p4)
            intersection = seg_intersect(p1, p2, p3, p4)
            x_new.append(intersection[0])
            #
            if (s_new > 0) and (s < 0):
                y_upper.append(intersection[1])
                y_lower.append(np.min((y_right[i], y_right[i-1])))
                dx = (intersection[0]-x_left[i])
                x_new.append(intersection[0]+dx)
                y_upper.append(y_left[i+1])
                y_lower.append(y_left[i])
            if (s_new < 0) and (s > 0):
                y_upper.append(np.max((y_right[i+1], y_right[i])))
                y_lower.append(intersection[1])
                dx = (intersection[0]-x_left[i])
                x_new.append(intersection[0]+dx)
                y_upper.append(y_right[i])
                y_lower.append(y_right[i+1])
        #
        s = s_new
    y_upper.append(y_left[-1])
    y_lower.append(y_left[-1])
    x_new.append(x_right[-1])
    #
    return x_new, y_lower, y_upper
```

I'm attaching a figure that shows the results from `fill_betweenx()` to show the additional area I want to shade.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C97In.png)

Comment: Do you definitely want an x-offset and not a y-offset?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do. I'm accounting for an predicted error in the x-property, and I want to shade the area that shows the +/- error.

Comment: It's not clear what should be below the curve. Should it not be a straight line connecting the cusps of the two shaded regions?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be a straight line with that triangle area shaded as well. So if you were to drag the curve from left to right, I want the whole area shaded in the plot. If I could find all the points of the cusps that define the shaded area I want, which is what I was trying to do, then I can just use the regular fill_between to do it, I think